# How to merge a 2 dimensional array into an existing array from inside a loop in php

Tags: php, arrays, merge, array-merge

I am having the following function, where I am getting list of ultrasounds for a given surgery by using

```
$hmo_claim_generate = new HMOClaimGenerate();
$services = $hmo_claim_generate->generateUltrasounds($hospital_id, $patient_id, "CONSULTATION", $id);
```

Below is the function itself which is part of a class file HMOClaimGenerate.

```
    // Generate Ultrasounds
//*********************************************************************************
public function generateUltrasounds($hospital_id, $patient_id, $service_type, $service_type_id)
{
    $mysql = new Mysql();

    $hospital_id = intval($hospital_id);
    $patient_id = intval($patient_id);
    $service_type_id = intval($service_type_id);

    $sql = "SELECT ultrasound_id FROM ". TABLE_HOSPITALS_ULTRASOUNDS ." WHERE hospital_id=$hospital_id AND patient_id=$patient_id AND request_from_type = '$service_type' AND request_from_id=$service_type_id AND payment_type = 'HMO' AND fee_status = 'BILLED' AND fee > 0";
    $totalRecords = $mysql->rowCount($query = $mysql->query($sql));

    if ($totalRecords > 0)
    {
        while($row = $mysql->fetchArray($query))
        {
            $ultrasound_id = $row["ultrasound_id"];
            $services["ultrasounds"][$ultrasound_id] = $ultrasound_id;
        }
    }

    return $services;
}
```

And this is the output

```
Array
(
    [ultrasounds] => Array
        (
            [102] => 102
            [203] => 203
        )
)
```

Now inside the function below, I am calling the above function

```
    // Generate Surgeries
//*********************************************************************************
public function generateSurgeries($hospital_id, $patient_id, $service_type, $service_type_id)
{
    $mysql = new Mysql();
    $string = new String();

    $hospital_id = intval($hospital_id);
    $patient_id = intval($patient_id);
    $service_type_id = intval($service_type_id);

    $sql = "SELECT surgery_id FROM ". TABLE_HOSPITALS_SURGERIES ." WHERE hospital_id=$hospital_id AND patient_id=$patient_id AND request_from_type = '$service_type' AND request_from_id=$service_type_id";
    $totalRecords = $mysql->rowCount($query = $mysql->query($sql));

    if ($totalRecords > 0)
    {
        $count = 0;

        while($row = $mysql->fetchArray($query))
        {
            $surgery_id = $row["surgery_id"];
            $services["surgeries"][$surgery_id] = $surgery_id;

            // Calling the function as displayed on top
            $ultrasounds = $this->generateUltrasounds($hospital_id, $patient_id, "SURGERY", $surgery_id);
        }
    }

    // Trying to merge the records from surgeries and ultrasounds into single array
    $services = array_merge($services, $ultrasounds);

    return $services;
}
```

Ultrasound here is a child or sub service falling under Surgery and I am trying to merge both the surgery and ultrasound into a single array but it has to be done from inside the while loop so that I can get the following result:

```
Array
(
    [surgeries] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1
            [4] => 4
            [10] => 10
        )
    [ultrasounds] => Array
        (
            [102] => 102
            [203] => 203
        )
)
```

Simple speaking I want to combine surgeries and ultrasounds in a single array called $services from where I can access the respective services such as

```
print_r($services["surgeries"][]);
print_r($services["ultrasounds"][]);
```

Please help me in sorting this issue. Tried lots of things but nothing is working at all for now.

Awaiting your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge them using a FOREACH.

```
$services='';
$i=0;
foreach($ultrasounds as $row){
    $services[$i]['ultrasounds']=$row;
    $i++;
}

$i=0;
foreach($surgeries as $row){
    $services[$i]['surgeries']=$row;
    $i++;
}
```

Where the variables ultrasounds and surgeries are the return from the query.

Comment: Can u elaborate where exactly I need to use foreach. Already quite confused and frustrated due to the issue. Appreciate your help though.

Comment: U can use the foreach as soon as u have both of the query returns, wich it seems is after  the while. Just remember, on my example $ultrasounds and $surgeries are the return from the querys.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a single array from `generateUltrasounds`

```
$ultrasounds = [];
while ($row = $mysql->fetchArray($query)) {
    $ultrasound_id = $row["ultrasound_id"];
    $ultrasounds[$ultrasound_id] = $ultrasound_id;
}

return $ultrasounds;
```

And then, in `generateSurgeries`, when you call `generateUltrasounds` you can do like you do for `['surgeries']` 2 lines above.

```
while ($row = $mysql->fetchArray($query)) {
    $surgery_id = $row["surgery_id"];
    $services["surgeries"][$surgery_id] = $surgery_id;

    // Calling the function as displayed on top
    $services["ultrasounds"][] = $this->generateUltrasounds($hospital_id, $patient_id, "SURGERY", $surgery_id);
}

return $services;
```

You no longer need to merge. This code is not tidy at all, but it should solve your problem.

LE - If you are still not happy with what's inside `$services['ultrasounds']`, you can do

```
while ($row = $mysql->fetchArray($query)) {
    $surgery_id = $row["surgery_id"];
    $services["surgeries"][$surgery_id] = $surgery_id;

    // Calling the function as displayed on top
    $services["ultrasounds"][] = $this->generateUltrasounds($hospital_id, $patient_id, "SURGERY", $surgery_id);
}

$services['ultrasounds'] = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $services['ultrasounds']);

return $services;
```

which will merge all the elements inside `['ultrasounds']` into a single array.

Comment: I tried this way as well, but in this case its showing only the surgeries and not the ultrasound. Ultrasound array somehow is getting reset due to loop or something. I tried print_r() on it and it displayed the ultrasound array, but outside the loop its showing only surgeries array inside the main service array.

Comment: Oh, you need `$services["ultrasounds"][]` instead of `$services["ultrasounds"]`

Comment: WARNING: ARRAY_MERGE() [FUNCTION.ARRAY-MERGE]: ARGUMENT #2 IS NOT AN ARRAY IN C:\PROGRAMDATA\WAMP\WWW\MHN\CLASSES\CLASS.HMOCLAIMGENERATE.PHP ON LINE 305
      ARRAY

Comment: Can you provide a function of how your functions look now? Or a screenshot of `var_dump($services['ultrasounds']); die;` before `call_user_func_array`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163825/discussion-between-ravenous-and-asnexplore).